# md-datepicker filter dates from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I've the following array with numbers that are representing days of week:

- 0 is for sunday
- 6 is for saturday

`var available = [1, 2, 3... whatever];`

It loads the days dynamically from for cycle:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var pos = data[i].position;
      available.push(pos);
    }
```

I assign a function called "severalDays" that filters the days available:

```
$scope.severalDays = function(date) {
     // I want access to available array here
  }
```

In my HTML I've the md-datepicker line:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="availableCalendar" md-date-filter="severalDays"></md-datepicker>
```

How I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

****SOLVED****

```
$scope.severalDays = function (date) {

      var day = date.getDay(); //I got generic day from 0 to 6 (0 for sunday, 6 for saturday);

      for(var i = 0; i < available.length; i++){

        var len = available.length; //length of available array

        var currentPos = available[i]; //current position of array

        var nextPos = available[(i+1)%len]; //next position of array

        var previousPos = available[(i+len-1)%len]; //previous position of array

        return day === currentPos || day === nextPos || day === previousPos; //THE RETURN

      }

    }
```